# How do I add a field to a Symfony2 form on preBind event?

Tags: php, forms, events, symfony

I need to modify a form on preBind (using Symfony 2.2).

Here is a segment of my preBind function in my EventSubscriber:

```
public function preBind(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $form->get('locationType')->setData('default');
}
```

However, when I submit the form, this value is not being saved. Am I missing a step? Do I need to call setData on the FormEvent object itself in order to propagate the new data?

Something that would really help me figure this out is to see the protected function customizeForm($form, $positions) completed in the example at the bottom of this page:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Not sure you are doing what you want the right way. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a Doctrine entity called Opportunity (volunteer opportunity). It has a field called locationType that cannot be null. The value of this field is set based on options selected in a drop down list of saved locations. An opportunity can have a locationType of "default," which amounts to the address of the nonprofit, "virtual" for remote volunteer opportunities, or "other" for new addresses. Also, previously entered addresses show up in the drop down list. If one of these is selected, then locationType is set to "other."

Comment: So depending on one choice filed, you have a text field set to a predefined value?

Comment: I want to dynamically change the contents of a form, after the form is submitted, but before it is bound to model format, so that when it is bound, some new data will be added.

Comment: I don't think you are going the right way. The example you show here is used to modify the form (FormType) not the data inside. Why don't you change the data from inside your controller?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, cheesemacfly. I did what you suggested, changing the data within the controller after submission.

Comment: Post your solution and accept it, this way the SO website doesn't stay full of unanswered questions :)

Comment: Changeing the data in the controller isn't the right place for that. Form events are the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cheesemacfly suggested, I ended up changing this data within the controller rather than trying to do it within the event subscriber.